# Java: True If statement in a For loop is causing the loop to break, but not executing the block

Tags: java, android

this is my first posting here, but I have done quite a bit of research before writing. I'm attempting to compare Strings using `String.equals()`, and (with the right data) the comparison is evaluating to `true`. I even threw in a boolean to check it. However, instead of executing the contents of the If block, it exits the For loop and returns null:

```
public WeatherInfo getWeather (Date date, ArrayList<WeatherInfo> weather) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
    String eventDate = sdf.format(date);
    for (WeatherInfo w : weather) {
        Date wDate = new Date(w.getEpoch() * 1000);
        String weatherDate = sdf.format(wDate);
        if (weatherDate.equals(eventDate)) {
            return w;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Anyone have any idea what could cause this to happen?

PS. Here's a screenshot of the relevant variables at the time of True evaluation (test is the check boolean)
[image: Variables]

Comment: What do you mean you `threw in a boolean to check it`? Are you sure `weather` actually has something in it?

Comment: I created a boolean that evaluates the same statement the If statement is evaluating, before the If gets it. When the statement should be evaluating to True, the boolean confirmed it. I also checked out the contents of weather, and it contains 10 WeatherInfo objects when it enters the For loop.

Comment: So you are saying `weatherDate.equals(eventDate)` is true? From what you have, I'm not sure what could be wrong. Could you please post more code, like the code in `WeatherInfo` as well as the code that calls `getWeather()` so we can see what you are passing in?

Comment: What values are being passed into the method?

Comment: Perhaps you should post the version that prints `true`, in case your test was wrong.  (It happens.  I've added code to print out values and then gone crazy trying to figure out what went wrong, until I realized that the code to print the values was screwed up.)

Comment: OK, how do you know it's returning `null`?  Is it possible that the code that calls `getWeather` isn't using the result correctly?

Comment: The weird thing is, if the If statement evaluates to false, it keeps going through all 10 items in the array before returning null. If I pick a date which matches element 1 of the array (2nd element), it only goes through the For loop twice before exiting and returning null.

Comment: Please post the code that you are using to call this, showing how you know it's returning `null`. Given the behaviour you just described, it doesn't sound like the problem is here.

Comment: ajb is right, sort of... I was relying on the Eclipse debug to show me what the function was returning, and it kept bypassing the "return w" line and executing the "return null" line, but afterwards, the code did in fact return w. Thanks everyone, sorry for the false alarm. *shakes fist at Eclipse*